# Format output as table

Tags: powershell

I wrote a simple loop that return a strings to a variable:

```
$global:OutMessage+="$($var) - test"
```

I want the output formatted as table like:

```
col1         col2

---         ----

var          test
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your output to `Format-Table`:

```
PS C:\> $var |Format-Table
col1 col2
--- ----
var test
```

If you want to store the formatted output as a string in a variable, pipe it to `Out-String` as well:

```
$Output = $var |Format-Table |Out-String
```